# Editor is not reloading file in eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, rich-text-editor

I have got some problem in application with editor, i am opening editors for showing file content. Now the problem is that when i open a file in editor and change the file content from backend and now when i open a new editor with that file then it shows file content same as that editor which is first open. Ideally required if resource is change in backend then it must show at editor too. but it is not happening in my case.

@IMP: I am useing CTabItem Item as a container on editor and adding page in it.

On finding the reason i think this statement i am using creating problem:

```
fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(new Path(filePath));
```

As it can be seen it is singleton class and it is returning opened instance not new one. But ideally there should be resource change event that should reload the file as eclipse does. If i implement `IResourceChangeListener` then what should i do to get reload sequence.

**Update**

```
   IFileStore fileStore = null;
    pageeditor = findEditorFromReference();
    fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(
            new Path(filePath));


    fileStore = fileStore.getChild("");
    //just assume reference to the code.
    openEditor = new Editor();//just reference of working 
    EditorInput editorInput = new EditorInput(
            fileStore, lineNo, filePath, title);
    Integer pageIndexNo = pageeditor.getPageIndexNo(file
            .getName());
    if (pageIndexNo == -1) {
        pageeditor.addPage(openEditor, editorInput, file
                .getName(), file.getName());
```

Comment: Are these files in the workspace? You should use `IFile` if so.

Comment: For the local file system the implementation of `IFileStore` just uses the normal Java `File` object so it should pick up changes.

Comment: No these are not in the workspace. these can have arbitrary path location say C:\, D:\ any where.

Comment: `IResourceChangeListener` only reports changes in the workspace so that won't help.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for response then any suggestion.

Comment: I don't see why a **new** editor does not pick up changes, as I said IFileStore just uses File so `openInputStream` should always give the latest contents.

Comment: @greg-449 I have updated the code as possible i can. pls see can u find any flaw. for now i dont have any resourceChangeListener.

Comment: Hard to tell but at a guess you are finding an existing editor or page and reusing it

Comment: Pls comment suggestions or solutions..